# React - jQuery - add onClick listener on document load

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I need to add an onClick listener on document load. I don't want to do it using state because of a few reasons. First, I want to create one rule that I can be used anywhere and always show the next element. Second, I also want to add fade or slide effects. Below code doesn't work.

```
componentDidMount() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".showNext").click(function() {
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
  });
}

if (!loadingData)
  render() {
    return(
      <div>

        <div className="showNext">Show element #1</div>
        <div style={{display:"none"}}>Element #1</div>

        <div className="showNext">Show element #2</div>
        <div style={{display:"none"}}>Element #2</div>

      </div>
    );
  }
} else {
  <div>Loading ... </div>
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `<div className="showNext">` be `<div class="showNext">` ?

Comment: No, in React you use `className` over `class` property, because in React that's a reserved word (`class`).

Comment: It's working for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/1z65rx3mqj but... just for the first render. After that, the references pointing to the DOM nodes are broken. You would need to attach those jQuery handlers in every `componentDidUpdate` too. This is very bad idea and it should be done using React event handlers, not jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using the `componentDidMount` method, it seems that you don't care about creating any function, update your code with this:

```
handleClickMethod = () => console.log('clicked')
render() {
  return(
    <div>

      <div className="showNext">Show element #1</div>
      <div style={{display:"none"}} onClick={this.handleClickMethod}>Element #1</div>

      <div className="showNext">Show element #2</div>
      <div style={{display:"none"}} onClick={this.handleClickMethod}>Element #2</div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Or even better! create a clickable component!

```
class Clickable extends Component {
  _handleClick = () => {
    console.log('clicked')
    this.props.onClick && this.props.onClick()
  }

  render() {
    const {...props} = this.props
    return <div {...props} onClick={this._handleClick}/>
  }
}
```

And use it like this in your main component:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>

      <Clickable className="showNext">Show element #1</Clickable>
      <div style={{display:"none"}}>Element #1</div>

      <Clickable className="showNext">Show element #2</Clickable>
      <div style={{display:"none"}}>Element #2</div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Anyway, for what you were trying to accomplish, you would be better with something more like this:

```
class Toggleable extends Component {
  state = {toggled: false}

  _toggleDiv = () => {
    this.setState({toggled: !this.state.toggled})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="showNext" onClick={this._toggleDiv}>{this.props.showText}</div>
        {this.state.toggled && <div>{this.props.text}</div>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And use it like this in your main component:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>

      <Toggleable showText={'Show element #1'} text={'Element #1'}/>
      <Toggleable showText={'Show element #2'} text={'Element #2'}/>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Welcome to modular programming!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In your example `<Toggleable showText={'Show element #1'} text={'Element #1'}/>` text={"can be complicated with lot's of logic behind"}, additionally, there is no way to add effects like `.slideToggle()` or `.fadeToggle()` to give a bit better visualization. That was my main point and that was a reason referring to jQuery and don't use React's State. But your code probably follows better React's practices.

Comment: `text` can be also a JSX element, or you just have to parse your text (if string) in a class function, also, for animations like slide and fade, just use plain CSS, you may also [check this](https://medium.com/@joomiguelcunha/amazing-react-animation-with-react-pose-3b67d9eb6e07) for a detailed guide over animations.

Answer (score 0):

In general, developers think that using jQuery within React application might be a bad idea but sometimes developers do want to use some jQuery magic like fading, sliding, etc. I personally found that React works best with ReactDOM using refs and targeting IDs and Classes with jQuery is definitely not the very best option, but ...

Back to my problem, it didn't work for me because I was using withTracker (Meteor/React) to load some data first so I was rendering dom with loading gif that didn't have my class. Then once data was loaded I was rendering the main content with the class I was targeting with jQuery in componentDidMount method.

My initial code works if targeted class renders the first time. I updated code in my initial question so there is no confusion.